# How to use Fill Handle to copy same value in the same steps of row in Excel

Tags: excel

confuse wiht the Title
Well sorry my English doesn't look good

but I'll try to describe what I mean

Suppose I have this kind of values

```
0   A   B   C   D   F   G   H   I   J
1       20     =B1
2       10     =B3
3       30     =B5
4       8      =B7
5       9      =B9
6       4      etc.
7       79
8       67
9       63
10      45
```

as you seen above
I want to copy every value in cell B in two step down to cell D with Fill Handle
How can I do it ?
Any Formula I can use regarding this ?

Thanks before

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow (see [help/on-topic]) unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on http://SuperUser.com

Answer (score 0):

In Cell D2 you can use the below formula, then drag down:

```
=INDEX(B:B,(ROWS($B$1:B1)*2)-1,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=OFFSET(B1,ROW()-1,)
```